# Use latest rate if no date is available

Tags: sql, oracle

Using oracle 9i with SQL developer

Can someone show me how to use the rate value for most recent date if there is no date is in table 2. Currently I have hard coded June 4 (Monday) to use Thursday’s rate as there is no rate of June 4th. Weekend was the easy part.  But I want to do this without having to manually hard code the holiday dates.  Can someone help?

```
select 
m.effective_date, 
m.value*al.rate

from table1 m, table2 al
where  
M.ID = al.ID 
AND M.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN '01-jun-12' and '30-jun-12'
and AL.value_date = m.EFFECTIVE_date -     ( case     
when m.EFFECTIVE_date = '04-jun-12' then 3
when to_char(m.EFFECTIVE_date,'DY') = 'SUN' then 2  
when to_char(m.EFFECTIVE_date,'DY') = 'SAT' then 1  
ELSE 0  
end ) 

table1 

Effective_date         Value
06-01-2012            100
06-02-2012            200
06-03-2012            600
06-04-2012           600
 All the way to 06-30-2012  



Table 2 (does not have weekends and some dates depending on UK holiday)

Value_date           Rate
06-01-2012           1.2
06-05-2012            1.5
06-06-2012            5.3
06-07-2012            1.5
06-08-2012            5.6
06-11-2012            1.5
06-12-2012             1.9
06-13-2012             2.1
```

Comment: What results do you expect? Can you show us an example result set? What does your query produce instead? It would also be helpful if you share the `CREATE TABLE` statements to define your tables, and the `INSERT INTO` statements to define your data, instead of ambiguous text. It makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.effective_date, 
m.value*al.rate
from table1 m, table2 al
where  
M.ID = al.ID 
AND M.EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN '01-jun-12' and '30-jun-12'
WHERE m.effective_dt = (SELECT MAX(effective_dt) FROM table1 x 
WHERE x.effective_dt <= a1.value_dt)
```